# Is it possible to use ARM aarch64 compiler to build with inline armv7l assemble code

Tags: arm, inline-assembly, arm64

```
this is a cpp file with inline ARMv7l asm code like this
```

```
  "pld        [%1, #96]     \n"
                    "vand q8, %q10, %q10     \n"
                    "vand q9, %q11, %q11     \n"
                    "vand q10, %q12, %q12     \n"
                    "vand q11, %q13, %q13     \n"
                    "vld1.f32 {d0-d1}, [%1]!   \n"
                    "vld1.f32 {d2-d3}, [%2]!   \n"
                    "vld1.f32 {d4-d5}, [%3]!   \n"
                    "vld1.f32 {d6-d7}, [%4]!   \n"
                    "vmul.f32 q12, q0, q9    \n"
                    "vmla.f32 q12, q1, q8    \n"
                    "vmul.f32 q13, q2, q9    \n"
                    "vmla.f32 q13, q3, q8    \n"
                    "vld1.f32 {d0-d1}, [%1]!   \n"
                    "vld1.f32 {d2-d3}, [%2]!   \n"
                    "vld1.f32 {d4-d5}, [%3]!   \n"
                    "vld1.f32 {d6-d7}, [%4]!   \n"
                    "vmul.f32 q12, q12, q11    \n"
                    "vmla.f32 q12, q13, q10    \n"
                    "vst1.f32 {d24-d25}, [%0]! \n"
```

now i want to compile this cpp as ArmV8a,will got error like this

```
 18s] {standard input}:2158: Error: unknown mnemonic `pld' -- `pld [x9,#96]'
[   18s] {standard input}:2159: Error: unknown mnemonic `vand' -- `vand q8,q16,q16'
[   18s] {standard input}:2160: Error: unknown mnemonic `vand' -- `vand q9,q17,q17'
[   18s] {standard input}:2161: Error: unknown mnemonic `vand' -- `vand q10,q18,q18'
[   18s] {standard input}:2162: Error: unknown mnemonic `vand' -- `vand q11,q19,q19'
[   18s] {standard input}:2163: Error: unknown mnemonic `vld1.f32' -- `vld1.f32 {d0-d1},[x9]!'
```

After checking the Armv8a is compatible to with Armv7l IA32 instructions,
My Question is

- is it possible to use armv8a compiler to compile this code ?
- if it is not possible , it is need to use armv8a instruction to rewrite this inline asm code ?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike with x86 where one GCC binary supports `gcc -m32` / `-m64` to build a 32-bit executable with the same compiler that can make a 64-bit executable, you need separate cross-compilers for ARM vs. AArch64.
(If you have clang, `clang -target arm -c` can at least compile an ARM object file, even with x86 clang: most clang builds support multiple back-end targets besides the one configured as the default.)

---

But if you're asking about using ARM32 assembly when compiling for AArch64, definitely not; you'll need to translate it yourself.  Just like if you had a separate `.S` file.  (GNU C inline asm literally works by emitting text into the `.s` file that GCC feeds to GAS, just expanding the `%operand` parts into text determined by GCC's choice for the operand constraint.)

It's usually fairly easy to port SIMD code from ARM32 to AArch64, but as far as getting the tools to accept it directly, you might as well be trying to feed them x86 or MIPS assembly.

---

If you can get the compiler to make decent asm from C intrinsics, do that because it will let the same code compile for both mode.

But that's unfortunately not always the case for ARM.  (Unlike x86 and PowerPC, where compilers generally do a good job with intrinsics, they can do pretty bad with ARM, especially if you need any horizontal stuff or mixing and matching 64-bit halves of 128-bit vectors.)

Comment: Thank you，peter.  seems i need to transleate armv7l assemble code  to armv8 aarch64